# Running Multiple Servers behind pfsense using single IP

Tags: virtualization, ip, pfsense

I have two webservers sitting behind a pfsense router. My ISP has issued me with a public IP. I have a LAN and OPT1 interface in pfsense. Is it possible to host these two webservers behind the single IP using virtual IP or VLAN function? If yes, how can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

Directly answering the question, not if you want them both to be on the default HTTP port (80).

Your options are:

- Run the 2 servers on different ports. This may be acceptable for small scale or personal use. Have pfSense port forward your chosen ports to the appropriate server, and mangle the internal port back to 80.
- Use a reverse proxy. This will allow both servers to appear to be on the same IP and port. pfSense can apparently do this.
- Ask your ISP for more public addresses, and use those addresses for your web servers.

I personally would choose option 1 if it's for personal/private use and URL appearances don't matter, or option 2 if the public will use these servers.